# getContentPane() returns null

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I have a class that extends `JFrame`. In its constructor I call `getContentPane()` and store it in a `Container`. However, `getContentPane()` seems to be returning null, as `System.out.println(container)` prints "null" and calling `container.setLayout(new BorderLayout)` throws a null pointer exception.

Some example code:

```
public class Example extends JFrame implements ... {
    public Example(){
        Container container = getContentPane();
        System.out.println(container);    //prints "null"
        container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());    //throws nullpointerexception
```

Additionally, calling `setLayout` on the class itself (i.e. `this.setLayout()`) also throws a `NullPointerException`, but if I understand the docs correctly this is because calling it on the frame simply delegates it to the frame's `contentPane`. I am using Eclipse, and it isn't pointing out any warnings or errors. The exception isn't very helpful because it only traces back two levels (main(), where the class is instantiated, to the `setLayout()` call).

I can post my whole code if necessary, but I wouldn't like to as this is for a class assignment and I don't want anti-cheat software to flag it.

Comment: Yep, probably going to need to see more :P

Comment: *"I can post my whole code if necessary,"*  Instead of of your whole code, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) about the content pane.  By the time you submit the completed code, the resemblance will be minimal. `public class Example extends JFrame implements ... {`  ..but this is probably not a case where the code should **`extend JFrame`** as opposed to simply using an instance of one.

Comment: you get the follwing error on the console. javax.swing.JPanel[null.contentPane,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$1,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. When I created the class in Eclipse, it autogenerated a bunch of methods, one of which was `getContentPane()`. The autogenerated method simply returned null, which was causing my problems. I got rid of all the autogenerated methods and it works now.